# How to view translated county in OctoberCMS rainlab.location plugin

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I've rainlab.location and rainlab.translate plugins installed. I translated countries and states in backend, but I can't view them translated in frontend. This is the code I'm using (from documentation):

```
 {% set countryId = countryId|default(form_value('country_id')) %}
 {% set stateId = stateId|default(form_value('state_id')) %}

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="accountCountry">Country</label>
 {{ form_select_country('country_id', countryId, {
    id: 'accountCountry',
    class: 'form-control',
    emptyOption: '',
    'data-request': 'onInit',
    'data-request-update': {
        'country-state': '#partialCountryState'
    }
  }) }}
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="accountState">State</label>
 {{ form_select_state('state_id', countryId, stateId, {
    id: 'accountState',
    class: 'form-control',
    emptyOption: ''
 }) }}
 </div>
```

It displays countries and states in English, even if I switched language!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be problem is in retrieving records

> https://github.com/rainlab/location-plugin/blob/master/models/Country.php#L71

when we call directly using `->lists('name', 'id');` translation relation is not loaded.

but if you change this line from

```
return self::$nameList = self::isEnabled()
     ->orderBy('is_pinned', 'desc')->lists('name', 'id');
```

to

```
return self::$nameList = self::isEnabled()
     ->orderBy('is_pinned', 'desc')->get()->lists('name', 'id');
                                ----- ^ <- this one
```

> It load translation relations and works fine.

for now you can change locally it should work, in future they might solve it.

> if you are concern about plugin update then you can extract that function and implement your own function.

Its just `form_select_country twig function` you can add to your own plugins with different name to make it work as you see there is only small code to copy :)

https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#extending-twig

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: but @HardikSatasiya if this plugin get updated then your changes will be lost.

Comment: I think the same too .. @Hardik, Is this possible to create our custom plugin to make these modifications by creating a hook or something ?

Comment: why not its just `form_select_country` twig functions you can add to your own plugins with diff name to make it work as you see there is only small code to copy :)